# Loop Postestimation Tests after Regression

Tags: loops, regression, stata

A loop for a number of regressions is performed. For each regression we need to conduct some heteroscedasticity tests. The following code unfortunately does not work:

```
gen p_hettest = .

quietly forvalues i = 1/10 {
reg y x if id == `i'
estat hettest if id == `i'
replace p_hettest=r(p) if id == `i'
}
```

Here is a data sample:

```
    clear
    input float(y x id)
     -.006994963  -7.015742e-06 1
      .002128173  2.7695405e-06 1
       .01837084  .000015578877 1
     -.018459747 -.000017552491 1
     -.008869853  -8.115663e-06 1
               0              0 1
       .00081374   1.039456e-06 1
        .0192536   .00001801726 1
     -.004777103  -2.800596e-06 1
      .006691461    4.95152e-06 1
     -.015235436 -.000015264517 1
       .03523033  -.00001293428 2
      .037114896   .00001956828 2
     .0041321944  -6.849998e-06 2
     -.000645176  .000012979223 2
     -.015742416  -4.716876e-06 2
      .005813865  -2.943401e-06 2
       .00220989  -4.920239e-06 2
      .003843212   8.216926e-06 2
      .013684767 -4.7989766e-07 2
       .02013146   3.841124e-07 2
        .0714285  2.9144696e-06 3
       .02564108   6.107174e-06 3
      -.01336905   -7.19949e-06 3
       0          .000031617565 3
      .034420278   3.418627e-06 3
      -.04042552   .00004654335 3
       .03571425  .000024398614 3
     -.002500042  -3.514139e-06 3
      -.04651165  -.00004515287 3
       .05263159  -7.449272e-06 3
       .08727269   -7.16101e-06 3
    end
```

A `r(101)` error occurs, indicating: `"if not allowed"`.

Is there an alternative way to loop regress-postestimation tests?

Comment: I can't replicate the error on my machine, could you give us some data that shows the issue so we can understand better what's going on?

Comment: @EricHB Data snippet added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `estat hettest` does not take `if` qualifiers. I am not familiar with the command, but I would guess that it uses only the values from the regression to perform the test.

If you modify your code to look like:

```
gen p_hettest = .

quietly forvalues i = 1/10 {
    reg y x if id == `i'
    estat hettest
    replace p_hettest=r(p) if id == `i'
}
```

you should be all set.

If you take off the `quietly`, you can see that the values for `r(p)` are changing for each call of `estat hettest`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought I tried that out, but I didn't.

Comment: Corrected typo (nothing here about `esttab`) and detail (`if` statement is something different).

Comment: Dima, glad it works! @NickCox sorry about that, was too quick posting yesterday, thanks for catching the typos